# Unknown character issue �

Tags: python, pandas

I have read a data frame into python with a column name that contains a euro symbol "price_€. Python sees the column as price_�. It will not allow me to refer to this column using either € or �

```
File "<ipython-input-53-d7f8249147e7>", line 1
df[price_€] = df[0].str.replace(r'[€,]', '').astype('float')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas how to remove this from the column name so I can start referring to it?

Comment: Are you saying when you print the dataframe you see `price_�`? If so then your problem is encoding

Comment: Hi Padraic, yes, when I print the frame i see `price_� `. Is there a way around this or do I need to manually change the input files?

Comment: How are you creating the dataframe?

Comment: Reading in from CSVs, the column header is Price (€) but then python prints them as `price_�`

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes using IPyhton on windows, seems to be reading all my columns in as objects too

Comment: Can you add a sample of your file?

Comment: The data can be found here  [link](https://www.propertypriceregister.ie/website/npsra/pprweb.nsf/PPRDownloads?OpenForm&File=PPR-2015.csv&County=ALL&Year=2015&Month=ALL ).. Also if you know of a way of converting object to int/float that would be useful too.

Comment: The data is cp1252 encoded so you need to specify the encoding

Comment: Why don't you change `price_€` to something like `price_euro`

Comment: The best comment to express your feelings: http://devopsreactions.tumblr.com/post/42346031350/random-unicode-character-in-a-column-name-cannot

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the euro sign in a variable name:

```
Identifiers (also referred to as names) are described by the following lexical definitions:

identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
```

You would need to use a string:

```
df["price_€"] ...
```

pandas actually has no problem for me with the euro sign:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]], columns=["£", "€"])

print(df["€"])
print(df["£"])
0    2
Name: €, dtype: int64
0    1
Name: £, dtype: int64
```

The file is cp1252 encoded so you need to specify the encoding:

```
mport pandas as pd
iimport codecs
df = pd.read_csv("PPR-2015.csv",header=0,encoding="cp1252")

print(df.columns)
Index([u'Date of Sale (dd/mm/yyyy)', u'Address', u'Postal Code', u'County', 
u'Price (€)', u'Not Full Market Price', u'VAT Exclusive', u'Description of Property', u'Property Size Description'], dtype='object')

print(df[u'Price (€)'])
0     €138,000.00
1     €270,000.00
2      €67,000.00
3     €900,000.00
4     €176,000.00
5     €155,000.00
6     €100,000.00
7     €120,000.00
8     €470,000.00
9     €140,000.00
10    €592,000.00
11     €85,000.00
12    €422,500.00
13    €225,000.00
14     €55,000.00
...
17433    €262,000.00
17434    €155,000.00
17435    €750,000.00
17436     €96,291.69
17437    €112,000.00
17438    €350,000.00
17439    €190,000.00
17440     €25,000.00
17441    €100,000.00
17442     €75,000.00
17443     €46,000.00
17444    €175,000.00
17445     €48,500.00
17446    €150,000.00
17447    €400,000.00
Name: Price (€), Length: 17448, dtype: object
```

Then to change to float:

```
df[u'Price (€)'] = df[u'Price (€)'].str.replace(ur'[€,]'), '').astype('float')

print(df['Price (€)'.decode("utf-8")])
```

Output:

```
0     138000
1     270000
2      67000
3     900000
4     176000
5     155000
6     100000
7     120000
8     470000
9     140000
10    592000
11     85000
12    422500
13    225000
14     55000
...
17433    262000.00
17434    155000.00
17435    750000.00
17436     96291.69
17437    112000.00
17438    350000.00
17439    190000.00
17440     25000.00
17441    100000.00
17442     75000.00
17443     46000.00
17444    175000.00
17445     48500.00
17446    150000.00
17447    400000.00
Name: Price (€), Length: 17448, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the lambda filter like below on the string

```
import string
s = "some\x00string. with\x15 funny characters"
filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, s)
```

output is

```
'somestring. with funny characters'
```

Comment: How is your answer related in any way to the OP's question?

Comment: Well filter the strings before using it as key. He asked how to remove the spl chars

Comment: Your answer is for a general string, this is string data in a pandas dataframe, as such your answer isn't applicable as it's not specific to pandas, also the OP made a basic error of not passing a string for the column name

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename) to rename the column name:

```
In [189]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['price_€'])
df

Out[189]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [price_€]
Index: []

In [191]:
df.rename(columns = {'price_€':'price'},inplace=True)
df

Out[191]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [price]
Index: []
```

Also `df[price_€]` is an invalid way of selecting a column, you need to pass a string so `df['price_€']` is the correct form.

Also this:

```
df[0].str.replace(r'[€,]', '').astype('float')
```

It's unclear what you're trying here, `df[0]` is going raise a `KeyError` again because to index a column you need to pass a string.

I also don't understand why you're casting the column to a float, you've not explained this part.